# Incorrect positioning of the divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I solve this unlucky positioning of divs? As you can see from the [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/xVzYdO) the #about div and the #link div are going overlayed.. This will be a full screen single page scrollable site and to set every div to have a full height I wrote the following rows of code which I think causes the problem.
Thank you in advance! :)

```
#main, #about, #link, #third {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

**EDIT**: The problem appear on small devices (even if you reduce the size of the window). The div with the ID #about is placed under the div with ID #link with the result that the text become illegible.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. What do you mean by "unlucky" positioning?

Comment: Apart from the dropdown menu on small screens having no background, I can't see an issue here. Please could you clarify on the **exact** setup when this issue occurs?

Comment: Sorry, I was not accurate; The problem appear on small devices (even if you reduce the size of the window). The div with the ID **#about** is placed under the div with ID **#link** with the result that the text become illegible. I hope that now the problem is clear.. Thank you again!

Comment: @paolopolix what i can see is that your title is overlapping on p text of first div so issue is with first div's p text..if you will lesser the text, your issue is gone..working on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `min-height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100vh`, so the divs can expand if needed.

Comment: as usual functional solutions are always the most trivial.. thanks @saison, it is working now! :)